# Proof that the set of complex numbers of the form $x + y\sqrt{2}$ satisfies the associativity, commutativity, distributivity and closure properties

Tags: field-theory, solution-verification

I'm currently reading *Linear Algebra*, by Hoffman and Kunze, and I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> The set of all complex numbers of the form $x + y\sqrt{2}$, where $x$ and $y$ are rational, is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1177569) and its comments, as well as [this thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/subfields-of-c-hoffman-kunze-la.538084/), I was able to arrive at a proof, but I'm unsure about the steps I used to prove that addition and multiplication are associative and commutative, that multiplication is distributive over addition, and that the set is closed under both operations.

My proof for those parts is as follows:

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be the set of all complex numbers of the form $x + y\sqrt{2}$, with $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then, $\mathbb{F}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, so, in order for $\mathbb{F}$ to be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{F}$ must be a field under addition and multiplication of complex numbers.

Because all elements of $\mathbb{F}$ are also elements of $\mathbb{C}$, and the operations of addition and multiplication for $\mathbb{F}$ are associative and commutative for members of $\mathbb{C}$, this also holds for elements of $\mathbb{F}$. The distributive property for multiplication can be proved analogously.

To prove closure under addition and multiplication, let $a$ and $b$ be elements of $\mathbb{F}$. Which means that $a = x_a + y_a \sqrt{2}$ and $b = x_b + y_b \sqrt{2}$, for some rational $x_a$, $y_a$, $x_b$ and $y_b$. Then, $a + b = (x_a + y_a \sqrt{2}) + (x_b + y_b\sqrt{2})$ and $a\cdot b = (x_a + y_a \sqrt{2})\cdot (x_b + y_b\sqrt{2})$.

Because $x_a$, $y_a$, $x_b$, $y_b$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are elements of $\mathbb{C}$, and the operations of addition and multiplication for $\mathbb{C}$ are being used, the associative, commutative and distributive properties can be applied to find that $a + b = (x_a + x_b) + ((y_a + y_b)\sqrt{2})$ and $a\cdot b = ( x_a x_b + 2(y_a y_b)) + (x_a y_b + y_a x_b)\sqrt{2}$.

Since $x_a$, $y_a$, $x_b$ and $y_b$ are rational, and the rationals are closed under addition and multiplication, $a + b$ and $a\cdot b$ are of the form $x + y\sqrt{2}$, where $x$ and $y$ are rational, so $\mathbb{F}$ is closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Your proof looks fine.  The associative, commutative, and distributive properties are [inherited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_property) from $\mathbb C$

Comment: I think you want to write $x,y \in \Bbb Q$ in the first paragraph of your proof.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you!

Comment: @AlexProvost You're right, I've edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: Congrats, you have almost shown that it is a subring. Something is Stil missing for subfield. So far, you could as well work with the set of integers $>42$, say

Comment: You still need to prove that the inverse of every nonzero element of $\mathbb F$ is in  $\mathbb F$

Comment: The inverse is in $\mathbb{F}$
$$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2} y}=\frac{x-\sqrt{2} y}{x^2+2 y^2}=\left(\frac{1}{x^2+2 y^2}\right)x+\left(\frac{-1}{x^2+2 y^2}\right) y\sqrt 2$$